# How to use same technique as ts omit, but applying it to object of concrete types?

Tags: javascript, typescript, http

I basically want to implement left | right join of two objects looking at their types.
For example, object **config** of default type RequestInit.

```
config = {
   headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
   },
}
```

And I have a customized **customConfig** of type, for example, CustomRequestInit that contains additional query params, which I later will join with url.

```
customConfig = {
   mode: 'cors',
   headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
   },
   params: {
    'tk': '2edr3q2afa3',
   }
}
```

This object has properties from RequestInit class, they should overwrite same properties in **config** object. Other properties from **customConfig** mustn't be in the final **config** object.
How do I left join this two objects by their types, ommitting additional keys that CustomRequestInit  brings in?

Comment: You mean like `Pick<CustomRequestInit, keyof RequestInit>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit unclear what you are trying to achieve.

This type adds properties from B which are missing in A (only adds new properties).

```js
type AddMissing<A, B> = A & Omit<B, keyof A>;
```